# Display slideshow of Images in front with song playing in background

Tags: android, multithreading, android-mediaplayer, android-image

I am writing a code for playing a song which is near about 3 min long in background and at the same time I want to show a slideshow of images in the front. There are two problems I am facing:
1. The song stops after 15 seconds.
2. the slideshow of images starts only after song stops.
Please help..thanks in advance...

My code is like this:

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);     
    setContentView(R.layout.mygame);
    final Handler mHandler = new Handler();
    try {
        AssetFileDescriptor afd = getAssets().openFd("AudioFile.mp3");
        MediaPlayer player = new MediaPlayer();
        player.setDataSource(afd.getFileDescriptor());
        player.prepare();
        player.start();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    final Runnable mUpdateResults = new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            animateandSlideShow();
        }
    };

    int delay = 15000;
    int period = 20000;

    Timer timer = new Timer();
    timer.scheduleAtFixedRate(new TimerTask() {
        public void run() {
            mHandler.post(mUpdateResults);
        }
    }, delay, period);
}
```